# Website layout height issue

Tags: html, css

Basically, I have no idea how to fix it, I need left and right columns to be 100% height from header to footer. so that I can resize the window and everything will stay in the same place.

However, my code doesn't work and the left and right columns overlap the footer.

HTML:

```
<section id="wrapper">

<header id="topHeader">
header
</header>

<section id="leftSection">
left<br>
</section>


<section id="middleSection">
middle
</section>

<section id="rightSection">
right
</section>



</section>
<footer id="footer">
footer
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 13px/22px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
border: solid 1px;

height: 100%;
}


#topHeader{
height: 40px;
}

#leftSection{
border: solid 1px;
border-color: #000000;

position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 150px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

height: 92%;
min-height:200px;
max-height:600px;
}

#rightSection{
border: solid 1px;
border-color: #000000;

position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top:41px;
margin-bottom: 41px;
width: 200px;
color: #564b47;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

height: 100%;
}

#middleSection{
border: solid 1px;
border-color: #000000;

margin: 0px 201px 0px 151px;
padding: 0px;

height:auto;
}

#footer{
border: solid 1px;
border-color: #000000;

clear:both;
height: 100px;
width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bPTtU/

Comment: Consider using `display: table-cell` rather than `absolute`. Take a look at the example: http://jsfiddle.net/26MGE/

Comment: Is it alright for HTML5 Layout standard?

Comment: As well , still can't get how to set up the height I want that height of the section will be fixed and if i resize window , ONLY height will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your header and footer have a fixed height, and both sidebars have a fixed width, you should be fine with the absolute positioning. Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/bPTtU/29/

Except for the header, all blocks are positioned absolute. 
The technique is quiet simple:

```
top: #px; /* outer height of the content above */
left: #px; /* outer width of the content to the left */
right: #px; /* outer width of the content to the right */
bottom: #px; /* outer height of the content below */
```

By setting more then 2 coordinates when positioning absolute (or fixed), you make the width and/or height dynamic, as you will notice when you resize my fiddle. Also note that I removed the borders, and changed it to background colors, cause borders add to the width/height of an element. You could keep the borders, but then you would have to take them into account (as well as the padding) when setting the coordinates.